# Interfaz gráfica de usuario (GUI) en R

Tags: r

Estoy aprendiendo R y hago esta consulta porque no he encontrado información con respecto a este tema. Me gusta realizar programas cuyos objetivos finales sean intentar entregar un programa a una persona que lo unico que busque, sea encontrar información a través del software. Qé herramientas me sugieren para crear un GUI o interfaz gráfica de usuario en R?. No he encontrado información de valor al respecto. Gracias por leer.

Comment: Bienvenido Jkuruc a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Tienes que tener en cuenta que R no es un lenguaje multipropósito como tantos otros, es un lenguaje de dominio y la interfaz de usuario es el propio lenguaje. O sea en R de fabrica no tienes ninguna funcionalidad que te permita construir una GUI como la de cualquier programa habitual. Sin embargo, tienes el paquete https://shiny.rstudio.com/ que te puede permitir construir algunas interfaces web responsivas bastante interesantes.

Comment: Con Rmarkdown puedes utilizar algunas de las funciones de html